# particles.js particles do not show up on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

So I was working with particles.js and it works on the safari browser (Im on a MacBook) but on chrome it throws the error and the particles do not show up.

```
Error pJS - XMLHttpRequest status: 404
particles.js:1558 Error pJS - File config not found
particles.js:1557 Error pJS - XMLHttpRequest status: 404
particles.js:1558 Error pJS - File config not found
```

Index.html

```
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="particles.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Styles.css

```
  #particles-js {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background: #000000;
  }
```

And I have the settings for the particles in a file called app.js.

Comment: Can you share your app.js? Usually you load your particle.js with a config as .json-File. How is your setup?

Comment: "File config not found" is a pretty clear error message, Investigate why its not found. Guess in the wild, wrong path to the file.

Comment: @YalcinKilic [app.js gist](https://github.com/ChaoticNebula5/chaoticnebula5.github.io/blob/main/app.js) and Marc the files are in the same directory.

Comment: @ChaoticNebula So when its working in safari and not in chrome then maybe a race condition where the app.js is loaded before the particle.js. Use the defer attribute. The app.js needs particle.js as dependency

Comment: So the defer attribute should be ```<script type = "text/javascript" src="particles.js" defer></script>``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because particle.js cant load two json-Files.

*/particlesjs-config.json* and */assets/particles.json*

Check your console in Safari where it is working. There have to be errors as well and check the particle.js documentation to set it up the right way.

Thats the part of particle.js where the request failes:

```
window.particlesJS.load = function (tag_id, path_config_json, callback) {
    /* load json config */
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", path_config_json);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
          var params = JSON.parse(data.currentTarget.response);
          window.particlesJS(tag_id, params);
          if (callback) callback();
        } else {
          console.log("Error pJS - XMLHttpRequest status: " + xhr.status);
          console.log("Error pJS - File config not found");
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
```

Comment: Those errors were there in the safari console, I made some changes to the code, the errors are gone but the particles are still not there in chrome

Comment: I fixed it thank you so much!